# Azure Mobile Services: migrate to non-Azure Windows Server

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am planning to use Windows Azure Mobile Services for a new project. As far as I am concerned, Mobile Services are closely tied to Windows Azure. So far, I'm pretty happy with Windows Azure.

What if, in the future, I decide to port the functionality to a non-Azure Windows Server? Is there a way to migrate an infrastructure built using Azure Mobile Services to a non-Azure Windows Server?

*I understand that Azure Mobile Services is a wrapper of common functionality that runs on top of Windows Server.*

Thank you in advance for your replies and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely possible to move the .NET runtime - This is just an ASP.NET Web API site, and it can be hosted anywhere that you might run ASP.NET. However, some features such as the login functionality will not be available.

For the Node.JS runtime, the actual process running the site is not available, so a migration would not really be possible. Although you could modify your scripts and move them into any Express site, I imagine this is not what you had in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Matt. What do you mean about the login functionality? I'm working using ASP.NET/C#.

Comment: The Mobile Services login features require the site to be hosted in Mobile Services. Normally you can provide Mobile Services with a client ID and secret, and it will handle the authentication flows needed to sign in mobile users. The feature is documented here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-get-started-users/

Comment: Awesome. I marked your comment as answer. Thank you very much for your assistance.